# Redirect network traffic to Proxy with Pfsense

Tags: pfsense

I have a network with 9 clients: 192.168.1.0/24

I need to redirect all traffic from 192.168.1.208 and 192.168.1.209 to an outside proxy server.

```
---------------
|192.168.1.201|--------|
---------------        |
|192.168.1.202|-----|  |
---------------     |  |
|192.168.1.203|--|  |  |  access internet with IP from my ISP
---------------  |  |  |  ---------------------    ----------
|192.168.1.204|--|--|--|--|PFSENSE 192.168.1.1|----|INTERNET|
---------------  |  |  |  ---------------------    ----------
|192.168.1.205|--|  |  |
---------------     |  |
|192.168.1.206|-----|  |              
---------------        |
|192.168.1.207|--------|
---------------                access internet with IP from my proxy server
|192.168.1.208|--|        ---------------------    --------------    ----------
---------------  |--------|PFSENSE 192.168.1.1|----|proxy server|----|INTERNET|
|192.168.1.209|--|        ---------------------    --------------    ----------
---------------
```

I want all trafic from 192.168.1.208 and 192.168.1.209 to access the internet using a proxy server (ip:port)

My question is: how do I setup pfsense to forward all traffic from 192.168.1.208 and 192.168.1.209 to some proxy and from that proxy to access the internet?

Comment: So far you haven't asked a question. Please read through the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: now I asked a question, do you have an answer?

Comment: And my down vote turns into an up vote! No, I personally don't have an answer for you but the point is that now you have amended your question, some member of the community may have a useful answer for you.

Comment: ...but you didn't say what kind of traffic nor what kind of proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PfSense to NAT port forward all 443/80 traffic to the external Proxy.

Here is an example of NTP and DNS being NAT(ed). What it does is any traffic that wants to use NTP ports or DNS is sent without the client knowing to the 192.168.1.1 address that responds.

I hope that helps.

[image: NAT pfsense example]